# Raven DB There is no reduce index named: 97

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I have a problem with a Raven db index that suddenly stopped working properly.

```
public class GetStockListForCustomerIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<CustomerStock, GetStockListForCustomerIndex.Result>
    {
        public GetStockListForCustomerIndex()
        {
            this.Map = docs => from d in docs
                               from i in d.Items
                               select new Result
                               {
                                   Id = i.Id,
                                   Country = d.Country,
                                   CustomerNumber = d.CustomerNumber,
                                   Type = d.Type,
                                   ItemNumber = i.ItemNumber,
                                   ItemName = i.ItemName,
                                   ItemNameSortingField = i.ItemName,
                                   UnitCost = i.UnitCost,
                                   Quantity = i.Quantity,
                                   ReservationDate = i.ReservationStartDate,
                                   Threshold = i.Threshold,
                                   AvailableQuantity = i.Available,
                                   QuantityLeft = i.QuantityLeft,
                                   Reserved = i.Reserved,
                                   AlwaysOne = 1,
                                   Currency = i.Currency
                               };

            this.Index(x => x.ItemNumber, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);

            this.Index(x => x.ItemName, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);

            this.Store(x => x.Id, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.Country, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.CustomerNumber, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.Type, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.ItemNumber, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.ItemName, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.ItemNameSortingField, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.UnitCost, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.Quantity, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.ReservationDate, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.Threshold, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.AvailableQuantity, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.QuantityLeft, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.Reserved, FieldStorage.Yes);

            this.Store(x => x.Currency, FieldStorage.Yes);
        }

        public class Result
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Country { get; set; }

            public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }

            public string Type { get; set; }

            public string ItemNumber { get; set; }

            public string ItemName { get; set; }

            public string ItemNameSortingField { get; set; }

            public Threshold Threshold { get; set; }

            public int Quantity { get; set; }

            public int? AvailableQuantity { get; set; }

            public int? QuantityLeft { get; set; }

            public int? Reserved { get; set; }

            public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }

            public DateTime ReservationDate { get; set; }

            public int AlwaysOne { get; set; }

            public string Currency { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

The query:

```
var result = this.Query
                            .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<GetStockListForCustomerIndex.Result>()
                            .Skip(this.PageSize * (this.Page - 1))
                            .Take(this.PageSize)
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.ReservationDate)
                            .ToList();
```

Gives wrong result with duplicates items every time the database is updated. I tried:

```
this.store.DatabaseCommands.ResetIndex("GetStockListForCustomerIndex");
```

When updating the data. That solved the problem but only temporary, now the index does not contain any data at all. 
 I get the following error logs

```
Message
Failed to execute indexing

Exception
Raven.Abstractions.Exceptions.IndexDoesNotExistsException: There is no reduce index named: 97
   at Raven.Database.Storage.Esent.StorageActions.DocumentStorageActions.TouchIndexEtag(Int32 id)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Database.Tasks.RemoveFromIndexTask.Execute(WorkContext context)
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexingExecuter.<>c__DisplayClass6.<ExecuteTask>b__5(IStorageActionsAccessor actions)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexingExecuter.ExecuteTask(HashSet`1 indexIds, Reference`1 foundWorkLocal)
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexingExecuter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<ExecuteTasksInternal>b__0(IStorageActionsAccessor actions)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action, EsentTransactionContext transactionContext)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexingExecuter.ExecuteTasksInternal()
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexingExecuter.ExecuteTasks()
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.AbstractIndexingExecuter.Execute()

Logged
a few seconds ago (12/15/17, 10:27am)

Level
Error

Logger
Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexingExecuter
```

And

```
Task for index: 97 (id: 97) has failed, details: Index: 97, Keys: customerstocks/8889089, customerstocks/8889090, customerstocks/8889091, customerstocks/8889092, customerstocks/8889093, customerstocks/8889094, customerstocks/8889095, customerstocks/8889096, customerstocks/8889097, customerstocks/8889098, customerstocks/8889099, customerstocks/8889100, customerstocks/8889101, customerstocks/8889102, customerstocks/8889103, customerstocks/8889104, customerstocks/8889105, customerstocks/8889106, customerstocks/8889107, customerstocks/8889108, customerstocks/8889109, customerstocks/8889110, customerstocks/8889111, customerstocks/8889112, customerstocks/8889113, customerstocks/8889114, customerstocks/8889115, customerstocks/8889116, customerstocks/8889117, customerstocks/8889118, customerstocks/8889119, customerstocks/8889120, customerstocks/8889121, customerstocks/8889122, customerstocks/8889123, customerstocks/8889124, customerstocks/8889125, customerstocks/8889126, customerstocks/8889127, customerstocks/8889128, customerstocks/8889129, customerstocks/8889130, customerstocks/8889131, customerstocks/8889132, customerstocks/8889133, customerstocks/8889134, customerstocks/8889135, customerstocks/8889136, customerstocks/8889137, customerstocks/8889138, customerstocks/8889139, customerstocks/8889140, customerstocks/8889141, customerstocks/8889142, customerstocks/8889143, customerstocks/8889144, customerstocks/8889145, customerstocks/8889146, customerstocks/8889147, customerstocks/8889148, customerstocks/8889149, customerstocks/8889150, customerstocks/8889151, customerstocks/8889152, customerstocks/8889153, customerstocks/8889154, customerstocks/8889155, customerstocks/8889156, customerstocks/8889157, customerstocks/8889158, customerstocks/8889159, customerstocks/8889160, customerstocks/8889161, customerstocks/8889162, customerstocks/8889163, customerstocks/8889164, customerstocks/8889165, customerstocks/8889166, customerstocks/8889167, customerstocks/8889168, customerstocks/8889169, customerstocks/8889170, customerstocks/8889171, customerstocks/8889172, customerstocks/8889173, customerstocks/8889174, customerstocks/8889175, customerstocks/8889176, customerstocks/8889177, customerstocks/8889178, customerstocks/8889179, customerstocks/8889180, customerstocks/8889181, customerstocks/8889182, customerstocks/8889183, customerstocks/8889184, customerstocks/8889185, customerstocks/8889186, customerstocks/8889187, customerstocks/8889188, customerstocks/8889189, customerstocks/8889190, customerstocks/8889191, customerstocks/8889192, customerstocks/8889193, customerstocks/8889194, customerstocks/8889195, customerstocks/8889196, customerstocks/8889197, customerstocks/8889198, customerstocks/8889199, customerstocks/8889200, customerstocks/8889201, customerstocks/8889202, customerstocks/8889203, customerstocks/8889204, customerstocks/8889205, customerstocks/8889206, customerstocks/8889207, customerstocks/8889208, customerstocks/8889209, customerstocks/8889210, customerstocks/8889211, customerstocks/8889212, customerstocks/8889213, customerstocks/8889214, customerstocks/8889215, customerstocks/8889216, customerstocks/8889217, customerstocks/8889218, customerstocks/8889219, customerstocks/8889220, customerstocks/8889221, customerstocks/8889222, customerstocks/8889223, customerstocks/8889224, customerstocks/8889225, customerstocks/8889226, customerstocks/8889227, customerstocks/8889228, customerstocks/8889229, customerstocks/8889230, customerstocks/8889231, customerstocks/8889232, customerstocks/8889233, customerstocks/8889234, customerstocks/8889235, customerstocks/8889236, customerstocks/8889237, customerstocks/8889238, customerstocks/8889239, customerstocks/8889240, customerstocks/8889241, customerstocks/8889242, customerstocks/8889243, customerstocks/8889244, customerstocks/8889245, customerstocks/8889246, customerstocks/8889247, customerstocks/8889248, customerstocks/8889249, customerstocks/8889250, customerstocks/8889251, customerstocks/8889252, customerstocks/8889253, customerstocks/8889254, customerstocks/8889255, customerstocks/8889256, customerstocks/8889257, customerstocks/8889258, customerstocks/8889259, customerstocks/8889260, customerstocks/8889261, customerstocks/8889262, customerstocks/8889263, customerstocks/8889264, customerstocks/8889265, customerstocks/8889266, customerstocks/8889267, customerstocks/8889268, customerstocks/8889269, customerstocks/8889270, customerstocks/8889271, customerstocks/8889272, customerstocks/8889273, customerstocks/8889274, customerstocks/8889275, customerstocks/8889276, customerstocks/8889277, customerstocks/8889278, customerstocks/8889279, customerstocks/8889280, customerstocks/8889281, customerstocks/8889282, customerstocks/8889283, customerstocks/8889284, customerstocks/8889285, customerstocks/8889286, customerstocks/8889287, customerstocks/8889288, customerstocks/8889289, customerstocks/8889290, customerstocks/8889291, customerstocks/8889292, customerstocks/8889293, customerstocks/8889294, customerstocks/8889295, customerstocks/8889296, customerstocks/8889297, customerstocks/8889298, customerstocks/8889299, customerstocks/8889300, customerstocks/8889301, customerstocks/8889302, customerstocks/8889303, customerstocks/8889304, customerstocks/8889305, customerstocks/8889306, customerstocks/8889307, customerstocks/8889308, customerstocks/8889309, customerstocks/8889310, customerstocks/8889311, customerstocks/8889312, customerstocks/8889313, customerstocks/8889314, customerstocks/8889315, customerstocks/8889316, customerstocks/8889317, customerstocks/8889318, customerstocks/8889319, customerstocks/8889320, customerstocks/8889321, customerstocks/8889322, customerstocks/8889323, customerstocks/8889324, customerstocks/8889325, customerstocks/8889326, customerstocks/8889327, customerstocks/8889328, customerstocks/8889329, customerstocks/8889330, customerstocks/8889331, customerstocks/8889332, customerstocks/8889333, customerstocks/8889334, customerstocks/8889335, customerstocks/8889336, customerstocks/8889337, customerstocks/8889338, customerstocks/8889339, customerstocks/8889340, customerstocks/8889341, customerstocks/8889342, customerstocks/8889343, customerstocks/8889344, customerstocks/8889345, customerstocks/8889346, customerstocks/8889347, customerstocks/8889348, customerstocks/8889349, customerstocks/8889350, customerstocks/8889351, customerstocks/8889352, customerstocks/8889353, customerstocks/8889354, customerstocks/8889355, customerstocks/8889356, customerstocks/8889357, customerstocks/8889358, customerstocks/8889359, customerstocks/8889360, customerstocks/8889361, customerstocks/8889362, customerstocks/8889363, customerstocks/8889364, customerstocks/8889365, customerstocks/8889366, customerstocks/8889367, customerstocks/8889368, customerstocks/8889369, customerstocks/8889370, customerstocks/8889371, customerstocks/8889372, customerstocks/8889373, customerstocks/8889374, customerstocks/8889375, customerstocks/8889376, customerstocks/8889377, customerstocks/8889378, customerstocks/8889379, customerstocks/8889380, customerstocks/8889381, customerstocks/8889382, customerstocks/8889383, customerstocks/8889384, customerstocks/8889385, customerstocks/8889386, customerstocks/8889387, customerstocks/8889388, customerstocks/8889389, customerstocks/8889390, customerstocks/8889391, customerstocks/8889392, customerstocks/8889393, customerstocks/8889394, customerstocks/8889395, customerstocks/8889396, customerstocks/8889397, customerstocks/8889398, customerstocks/8889399, customerstocks/8889400, customerstocks/8889401, customerstocks/8889402, customerstocks/8889403, customerstocks/8889404, customerstocks/8889405, customerstocks/8889406, customerstocks/8889407, customerstocks/8889408, customerstocks/8889409, customerstocks/8889410, customerstocks/8889411, customerstocks/8889412, customerstocks/8889413, customerstocks/8889414, customerstocks/8889415, customerstocks/8889416, customerstocks/8889417, customerstocks/8889418, customerstocks/8889419, customerstocks/8889420, customerstocks/8889421, customerstocks/8889422, customerstocks/8889423, customerstocks/8889424, customerstocks/8889425, customerstocks/8889426, customerstocks/8889427, customerstocks/8889428, customerstocks/8889429, customerstocks/8889430, customerstocks/8889431, customerstocks/8889432, customerstocks/8889433, customerstocks/8889434

Exception
Raven.Abstractions.Exceptions.IndexDoesNotExistsException: There is no reduce index named: 97
   at Raven.Database.Storage.Esent.StorageActions.DocumentStorageActions.TouchIndexEtag(Int32 id)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Database.Tasks.RemoveFromIndexTask.Execute(WorkContext context)
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexingExecuter.<>c__DisplayClass6.<ExecuteTask>b__5(IStorageActionsAccessor actions)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexingExecuter.ExecuteTask(HashSet`1 indexIds, Reference`1 foundWorkLocal)
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexingExecuter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<ExecuteTasksInternal>b__0(IStorageActionsAccessor actions)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action, EsentTransactionContext transactionContext)
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action)
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexingExecuter.ExecuteTasksInternal()
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexingExecuter.ExecuteTasks()
   at Raven.Database.Indexing.AbstractIndexingExecuter.Execute()
```

There is no index named 97 and there are no stocks with those ids in the database.
How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try resetting the index

Comment: I've tried that and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by reinstalling ravendb on hosting server

Comment: I am unsure but maybe this is more like a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ran in to this on an old legacy system. Upgrading to the latest 3.0 series fixed the problem without removing everything. We did have to reindex though.